# On file removal, deletion, erasing and friends thereof

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

- [delete](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/delete) ×196
- [remove](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remove) ×47
- [rm](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/rm) ×19
- [secure-erase](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/secure-erase) ×18
- [deleted](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/deleted) ×3
- [secure-delete](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/secure-delete) ×3
- [erase](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/erase) ×1

Surely we can give those poor tags some synonym love? I don't think they should *all* be merged into one master tag, but surely we can have something better than this can.

I suggest:

- [file-deletion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-deletion) ← delete, remove, deleted, erase
- [secure-erase](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/secure-erase) ← secure-delete
- leave [rm](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/rm) alone.

Comment: Interestingly, none of these have followers.

Comment: @Tshepang eh, hardly an important statistic.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that there might be non-file-related questions in these tags, so someone might first want to go through them. Anyhow, with the low number of questions that isn't really a problem... :-)

Comment: Yeah, tagging was never meant to be perfect.

Comment: Non-file related? What can you delete or erase other than a file?

Comment: Raw data. Entries in a file. ... The different contexts require different tools. That's why whether or not it is raw, an entry or a file or some other medium or storage type does matter a lot...